# $.getJSON() doesn't work correctly the first time the script runs, but it does the second time. How do I make it run the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here's my script which I type into Firebug:

```
var jsonData;

$.getJSON("./js/ohno.JSON",function(data){
    jsonData = data;
});

console.log(jsonData);
```

Here's the .JSON file contents:

```
{"oh":"no"}
```

The first time I run the script in Firebug, it returns "undefined"

The second time I run it (without refreshing the page) it returns the Object.

If I refresh, the same thing happens -- first time running returns "undefined", and second time running it returns the Object.

The .JSON file is

How do I make it so that it returns the Object the first time I run the script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

getJSON is async; meaning that script execution will continue, while it still loads the data.

You have to wait until it finishes.

```
var jsonData;

$.getJSON("./js/ohno.JSON",function(data){
    jsonData = data;
    console.log(jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the `console.log` (and any other code you want to run on `data`) inside the callback function:

```
$.getJSON("./js/ohno.JSON",function(data){
    jsonData = data;
    console.log(jsonData);
});
```

You can also use [`.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) if you feel the need to keep it separate.

Answer (score 3):

`getJSON` is asynchronous, which is why you have to provide a callback to handle the data. The request is fired off, but it hasn't completed by the time you get to your `console.log`, so the value is undefined. It finishes a short time later and sets the variable.

Move your `console.log` handler into your callback, and all should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous `function` is an asynchronous callback, so it gets called **after** your `console.log`.
Here is the right way to do it :

```
var jsonData;

$.getJSON("./js/ohno.JSON",function(data){
    jsonData = data;
    console.log(jsonData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The getJSON function is asynchronous, so the success callback function only gets executed once the request finishes. Your console.dir() is initially executing before the response happens.

Put the console.dir() inside your getJson handler function.